Running Cucumber/Playwright tests in Microsoft Edge with Single Sign on
Need some help as I'm new to Cucumber and Playwright.
System has a single sign on option, which is currently signed on through my instance of Edge.
I need to run my tests through the single sign on, so using the inbuilt Chromium instance doesn't work as it goes in via Incognito mode.
I've got my code to successfully open Edge and run the initial part of the test.
What I'm unable to do is change the test to open Edge in 'not incognito' mode and actually click the link and go through to the application.
My research on this has led me to believe that 'launchPersistentContext' should help, but I can't get my code to work with that.
The code I'm currently using is:
const { Given, When, Then, Before, After, setDefaultTimeout } = require("@cucumber/cucumber");

const { chromium, expect, test } = require("@playwright/test");

const { Page } = require("playwright");

setDefaultTimeout(10 * 1000);

let page, browser;

Before(async function () {
    browser = await chromium.launch({ channel: 'msedge', headless: false });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    page = await context.newPage();
});

Given("User navigates to the Staging Environment Login", async () => {
    await page.goto("<website>");
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000); //5 secs
    expect(page).toHaveTitle('Sign in to Website');
    const pageTitle = await page.title();
    console.log("Page title is: " + pageTitle);
});

When("using the SSO log in", async function(){
    await page.waitForLoadState();
    await page.getByTitle('saml').click();
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000); //2 secs
  
  });


After(async function () {
    await browser.close();
});

I'm getting the Edge browser instance from the Playwright.config.js

Try
  const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext("userDataDir", {
    channel: "msedge",
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await context.newPage();


How would you recommend closing the browser in an 'After' function? browser.close() and context.close() are giving me errors, claiming that the page or context has been closed.

I'd suggest you not reinvent the wheel and use https://github.com/vitalets/playwright-bdd if you want to have BDD or use built-in Steps and @playwright/test as they suggest
